# I have a list of separation/displacement vectors, how can I calculate the location vectors?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, vectors, geometry, software

> I need to calculate some location vectors which from separationdisplacemen vectors which are generated from the formula $\vec{R}_{i+1} - \vec{R}_{i}$, where $\vec{R}_{i}$ being a location vector.

A little background:
I have some monomers where I have their separation vectors, but what I want to get is the monomer locations.

How can I do this? Maybe a toy example can help me understand this a bit better.

EDIT:

I am given a list of separation vectors from a function called frc. Here is the help print out:

```
This function generates nruns configurations of a length N polymer, 
  using the freely rotating chain model with fixed bond angle theta.
  It is returned as a single 3 x N x nruns tensor of separation vectors.
  The first dimension is the x,y,z coordinates; the second specifies which 
  monomer on the chain; and the third specifies which configuration.
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Do all of these separation or displacement vectors involve displacements from the same reference point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean something like this:

[image: Polymer chain]

where the $\hat{r}_i$ are the separation vectors and you want to calculate the vector $\hat{R}$. The answer is simply that $\hat{R}$ is the sum of all the vector that lead up to it so in this case:

$$ \hat{R} = \hat{r}_0 + \hat{r}_1 + \hat{r}_2 + \hat{r}_3 + \hat{r}_4 + \hat{r}_5 $$

The only catch is that you need to use [vector addition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorAddition.html) when adding the vectors. You don't say how you're given the separation vectors, i.e. in what format, but they are often given as their $x$, $y$ and $z$ components:

$$ \hat{r} = \left(r_x, r_y, r_z \right) $$

In this case you add the vectors simply by adding their components, so for example;

$$ \hat{a} + \hat{b} = \left( x_a + x_b, y_a + y_b, z_a + z_b \right) $$

Comment: Thanks John, I actually have to calculate the locations for each monomer in this freely rotating chain. I can calculate the end to end or R when I sum up each of the location vectors. So the real question is how can I calculate the locations of each of the monomers when I am given a list of separation vectors in the format (x,y,z)

Comment: @Kevin: The location of the $n$th monomer (relative to whatever end of the chain you start at) is just $R_n = r_0 + r_1 +\, ...\, + r_n$.

Comment: Ah! okay, so I can do something like cumulative sum (of the separation vector) along the chain and get my location for each monomer. Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin: yes, exactly.